# Any internal way to declare dispatchable events in the class so that the list of them accessible from outside?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I would like to declare in my class a set of events that get dispatched by it and then use this information from controller class to automate addition of the event listeners. Is there a language structure for this in Action Script 3? And what you might think of the approach like this - good, bad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `[Event]` meta tag for your class along with `describeType()` method.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.describeType;

    [Event(name="test",type="TestEvent")]
    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public function Test()
        {
            var description:XML = describeType(this);
            var meta:XMLList = description.descendants("metadata");
            var events:XMLList = meta.(attribute("name") == "Event");
            trace(events.toXMLString());
            /*
            trace output:
            <metadata name="Event">
                <arg key="name" value="test"/>
                <arg key="type" value="TestEvent"/>
            </metadata>            
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Meta tags: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html#159710

describeType(): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29

Btw, if you declare your custom events like this, you will also get appropriate code hints in Flash Builder.